# After invalidateOptionsMenu() ; Menu items no more clickable

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-menu

So I have been updating a menu item icon based on the connection status with a sensor.

To update the menu item icons, I need to invalidate menu options. After invalidating the menu options, the items are no more clickable.

Although, I have encountered on [GitHub](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/510) bug report for this but it is quite old and I suppose it should have been fixed by now. Has anyone else encountered the similar problems?

I have tried on fix but I suppose that's not the way to do it, which is to call invalidateOptionsMenu() inside each callback from the sensor. and it was working fine.

But I need to know that for sure, if it is a bug or not.

```
private String statusOne = "not_found";
private String statusTwo = "not_found";


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .... 
    sensor_one.setConnectListener(new TempratureConnectListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void TempratureConnectCallback(boolean b) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() { 
                                sensor_one = "connected"; 
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void TempratureDisconnectCallback() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               sensor_one = "disconnected"; 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

    sensor_two.setConnectListener(new ShakeConnectListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void ShakeConnectCallback(boolean b) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() { 
                                sensor_two = "connected"; 
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void ShakeDisconnectCallback() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               sensor_two = "disconnected"; 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.connectwithsensor1:
            sensor_one.start();
            break;
        case R.id.connectwithsensor2:
            sensor_two.start();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) { 

    switch (statusOne){
        case "notfound":
            menu.findItem(R.id.sensorOne).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_not_found));
              break;
        case "connected":
            menu.findItem(R.id.sensorOne).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_connected)); 
            break;
        case "disconnected":
            menu.findItem(R.id.sensorOne).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_disconnected)); 
            break;

    } 

    switch (statusTwo){
        case "notfound":
            menu.findItem(R.id.sensorTwo).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_not_found));
              break;
        case "connected":
            menu.findItem(R.id.sensorTwo).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_connected)); 
            break;
        case "disconnected":
            menu.findItem(R.id.sensorTwo).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_disconnected)); 
            break;

    }  

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: @PhanVanLinh if you are saying correct then I need to fix this asap.

Comment: sorry, look like I understand wrong about this function. I think when we call `invalidateOptionsMenu`, it will call `onPrepareOptionsMenu` but I just test and see it dont call

Comment: okay okay no problem.

Comment: I just verify again. In theory, if we call `invalidateOptionsMenu`, `onCreateOptionsMenu` then `onPrepareOptionsMenu` will call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu(). However, if we call `invalidateOptionsMenu` inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` not called (I test with android 8, compileSdkVersion 29). Can you help me check in your case, `onPrepareOptionsMenu` call again after `invalidateOptionsMenu` or not

Comment: beside that, you shouldn't use `invalidateOptionsMenu` inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` because it don't help you anything.

Comment: let me check your suggestions and I will get back to you